# How to register .DLL files in Windows 8 64-bit OS?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opengl, dll

I searched everywhere but found no result on how to register a **.DLL** file in **Windows 8 64-bit**.
See my 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231421/glut32-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-visual-studio-express-rc-2013-for-des?noredirect=1#comment28464019_19231421) wuestion too where I tried everything and then someone said that I have to register .DLL files. But how?

Answer (score 8):

Only COM servers can be registered, glut32.dll is not a COM server.

A standard mistake is copying a 32-bit DLL into c:\windows\system32.  They need to be copied to c:\windows\syswow64 instead, the home for 32-bit executables on a 64-bit version of Windws.  In general certainly best to avoid, messing with the Windows directories is always a mistake.  Copy the DLL into the same folder as your EXE instead.  Best done by a post-build event in your project.

Comment: Now http://scontent-b-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/988314_3366365135587_679254571_n.jpg is the error

Comment: As I said, you really do need to stop trying to register that DLL, it is not a COM server.

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple, add via Windows Desktop GUI:

1) Go to "Control Panel" -> "System" -> "Advanced System Setting".

2) At the "Advanced" TAB press on the lower right the button -> "Environment Variable".

3) Add any path you want to "Path" variable, make sure to put at the end ";".

4) re-start you computer.

Done :-)

From the cmd line, you can view the "Path" values by typing:

echo %PATH%

Answer (score -4):

On Windows 8.1 Pro:

1. Copy `xxx.dll` file into the `c:\windows\System32` folder
2. Right-click on "Command Prompt" and select "Run as Administrator"
3. Then register the file: `regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\xxx.dll`